# Sharing Modules in a different folder in vb.net using Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing generic modules for multiple programs - for example, a series of parsing functions or array handling routines.  I would like multiple programs to access this so that if any updates are made to the generic module, the changes are shared across all projects.  I am using VB.NET, but this is not a VB question, it's more for the studio.

Here's the scenario:

I copied the generic routines into their own folder at the Visual Studio project level.
[image: Generic Modules]

I then deleted the modules out of the project and could only figure to load them back into the project was using the ADD > Existing module and I pointed to the modules in the generic folder:
[image: Adding an existing item]

However, even though I point to the generic folder when I added the modules, they are copied into the current project's folder and when looking at properties, it shows they are in the local project:
[image: Desired Result]

**My question is: other than using the Add Existing function, is there any other way to have VB use modules in a different folder?**

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio (Used VB6 IDE for ages).  I have explored through VS as much as I can and even searched the Internets (LOL) but I can't even come up with good search terms for something like this.

I also understand this may the wrong place for this and apologize in advance - if it's in the wrong place please let me know where I should post it.

Perhaps sharing modules across multiple modules may not be the best way to do things - just in my mind, I can test a module with a test program, then put it into the "real" program and if I want to add enhancements to the module, I can go back to my test program (plus of course share with other modules).  I also know this is not OOP so don't flame me please.  If you have other constructive ideas, I would be very glad to hear it.  By the way, after being on Stack Overflow for a couple of years, this is my FIRST question ever.

Answer (score 2):

In the Add Existing Item dialog, click the down arrow next to Add, then click Add as Link.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much - I never saw that dropdown - worked perfectly

Comment: @cardmagik the one goofy thing about `Add as Link` is that you cant Edit and Go with them.  They are basically ReadOnly at runtime - I *think* it is because they might be part of more than one running (EXE and DLL) and you cant have one change the other while it is running.

Comment: @Plutonix: I don't think that's true

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/700280/edit-and-continue-does-not-work-for-vb-linked-files  Apparently it is not supposed to be that way, I have never ever been able to Edit and Continue since VS2005.  I thought it was by design,

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you for the tip - I don't seem to use Edit and Continue yet much.  I always terminate the program (because I'm a n00b obviously).  But I can live with that as long as I can share my generic version amongst multiple programs.  I mean really, who wants to write the same parsing routine over and over again?

Comment: @cardmagik: You should consider writing a Class Library project instead.